Why can't my fields be bound in the mentioned SQL query?
Here's some information on the relevant fields in my database:
SELECT *
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE UPPER(TABLE_NAME) LIKE '%Own_Customer.PRODUCTS%'
  AND ((UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) = 'ID') OR (UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) = 'NAME'))

Result:



TABLE_CATALOG
TABLE_SCHEMA
TABLE_NAME
COLUMN_NAME
ORDINAL_POSITION
COLUMN_DEFAULT
IS_NULLABLE
DATA_TYPE
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
NUMERIC_PRECISION
NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX
NUMERIC_SCALE
DATETIME_PRECISION
CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG
CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA
CHARACTER_SET_NAME
COLLATION_CATALOG
COLLATION_SCHEMA
COLLATION_NAME
DOMAIN_CATALOG
DOMAIN_SCHEMA
DOMAIN_NAME




Cerastore_Own_Customer
dbo
Own_Customer.Products
Name
8
NULL
NO
varchar
255
255
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
iso_1
NULL
NULL
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
NULL
NULL
NULL


Cerastore_Own_Customer
dbo
Own_Customer.Products
Id
10
NULL
NO
uniqueidentifier
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL



SELECT [Own_Customer.Job].Name,[Own_Customer.Job].Status, [Own_Customer.JobPart].Id, [Own_Customer.JobPart].SequenceNr, [Own_Customer.JobPart].ProductId, [Own_Customer.Products].Name
  FROM [Own_Customer.Job], dbo.[Own_Customer.JobPart]
  WHERE [Own_Customer.Job].Id = [Own_Customer.JobPart].JobId AND
        [Own_Customer.JobPart].ProductId = [Own_Customer.Products].Id
ORDER BY [Own_Customer.Job].CreationDate, [Own_Customer.Job].Name, [Own_Customer.JobPart].SequenceNr, [Own_Customer.JobPart].Id

Result:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "Own_Customer.Products.Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Own_Customer.Products.Name" could not be bound.

Some examples of the content in the columns "Name" and "Id" of "[Own_Customer.Products]":



Name
Id




CHE APPELZUUR COATEC C12-65 (CONT)
D1B79DE6-FAE5-4568-96FC-FA12EF2C4B02


CHE BIND GUAR 5000 CPS  (CONT)
AE5525E4-0230-43BC-A8D4-C21501F139A5


CHE FOSF SAPP B285 - E450I (CONT)
F6C6C365-DBC5-449D-A0ED-70C98F89B197


CHE FOSF STPP XINGFA (CONT)
510696EE-F975-4490-AF34-EBE6938E2D4F


CHE NATRIUM BICARBONAAT (CONT)
FDD76641-98DF-47FA-8C04-389D324B5BCE



What can I do in order to launch the desired SQL query? (The one with information about Jobs, JobParts and Products)
... just to start: why does SQL-Server think that the mentioned fields are multi-part identifiers? They're just names of IDs, nothing multipart about them.
Some more information
I don't know if this is relevant, but next to the dbo.Own_Customer.Products table, I also have a dbo.Products table.
I do not believe my question is a duplicate of this one. That question mentions quite a lot of possible answers, but the simple fact that I had forgotten to add a table in the FROM-clause is not mentioned or not easy to be found.

Own_Customer.Products isn't part of your join, so how can sql server refer to the columns. Shouldn't it be Own_Customer.Job? Btw, you should check out on how to use aliases as well as joins, these might save you a lot of typing in the long run

Note that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS contains information about columns, not fields.

Anything with a . in it (used where an identifier is expected) is a multipart identifier as the dots separate the parts.

@siggemannen: I admit, I had written one "dbo" too many, this has been corrected in the edit of my question, but else I don't understand your remark: I have a list of jobs. Every job has a list of jobParts and every jobPart has a list of Products. The last criterion of my query AND [Own_Customer.JobPart].ProductId = Own_Customer.Products].Id clearly says that Own_Customer.Products is a part of the join, isn't it?

@MartinSmith, does this mean a dot never should be used in identifiers? Even if all identifies are delimited.

@MartinSmith: does the term "multi-part identifier" talks about the filename (like "Own_Customer.Products") or about the content (like "CHE APPELZUUR COATEC C12-65 (CONT)")?

@jarlh - I was just addressing the "nothing multipart about them" comment at the end of the question

Ok, but a JobPart doesn't contain products, they are contained in another table called Products? But you don't join in the table anywhere in your code. To access the data from a Table called X, the table called X must be somewhere in the FROM or JOIN part of your query. This is basic SQL. Your code should look something like: select * from Job j inner join JobPart jp ON jp.ID = j.ID INNER JOIN Products p ON p.ID = jp.ProductID or something like that

@siggemannen: Thanks a lot! The tablename was not in the "FROM"-part of the query, you're so right. Can't they invent a clearer error message for that? :-) :-) :-) You can write your last comment as an anwer, I'll accept it.

Strange, the error message complains about errors in line 10 and line 7, but the query only has 5 rows.

I assume the OP has rows before the query; perhaps a USE MYDatabase;\nGO\n\n (where \n is a newline).

@siggemannen: I'm sorry. I have asked you to write your comment as an answer but in the meantime somebody has closed my answer, making this impossible. I've edited my question again and launched the corresponding "Reopen" request, hopefully somebody will pick up on that.

@Dominique "That referred question mentions quite a lot of possible answers," That's the point. There is an answer that covers specifically why you got the error as well; you forgot to reference the table.

@ThomA, I see. However, I can't find any more-than-2-part identifiers in the given query. Isn't [Own_Customer.Products].Id 2 parts?

It's alright, the important part is that you got it working

@jarlh: good catch! I have in fact different SQL queries in my edit window and I had put one of them in comment, causing the line numbering to be off.

I'm not sure of your point, @jarlh, a multipart identifier is a multipart identifier, regardless of if it contains 2 parts or more . We don't need many versions of the same problem which are specific to 2, 3, 4 and 5 part naming.

@ThomA: Please! That answer is the fourteenth (!!!) one and although it mentions the solution indeed, it's really not that clear.

@Dominique The error is pretty clear, if you look up its documentation  (which should always be the first step before asking a question here)

If you feel it's unclear, you can always post your own answer to the duplicate, @Dominique .

@ThomA, the error message makes me lost. It says 'The multi-part identifier "Own_Customer.Products.Id" could not be bound', which to me looks like a 3 part identifier, but OP wrote [Own_Customer.Products].Id which I interpret as a 2 part identifier.

Yeah, that the OP has periods (.) in their object names is a problem unto itself, @jarlh . They should really shouldn't be, and should also be aliasing their objects. That the error doesn't put quotes around the objects in a scenario is a flaw with the error messaging, but fundamentally this changes nothing about why the OP is getting a the error and what the error means, which is explained in the duplicate.

@jarlh: I can't agree more! As you can see in my question, I even went looking into the content of my identifier columns, searching for text separators (spaces, hyphens, ...) as an explanation for the error message :-)

Also it's 2024, you should have adopted the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax years ago; it has been around for 32 years now. Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs

As mentioned above, the problem is that your [Own_Customer.Products] table is referenced in the SELECT and WHERE clauses, but is missing from the FROM clause (similar to Bhavik's answer way down in the linked duplicate question). Another (non-critical) problem is using old-style joins. Whoever is still teaching this style needs to stop. The use of table-aliases would also significantly improve readability. See this db<>fiddle for a demo that includes the original query, a minimally fixed query, and a version that uses ANSI joins and table aliases.
